# Application does not pick updated values after modifying App.Config file c#

Tags: c#

I have developed a winforms application which consists of a file path value (fetching crystal reports) in add key of app.config file.
I have **installed** the application and trying to change the file path (**in app.config as well as exename.exe file**) from old to new but the application doesnt take new crystal reports file path instead retrieves old data. 
Am i missing any other file to be updated ? Kindly help to get it solved ASAP.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to change `App.config`, as that file will be copied to `exename.exe.config` when you build.

After installing your program, you'll need to change your `exename.exe.config` file to pick up your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the setting you are trying to change in `exename.exe.config` file is set to User scope rather than Application.

From Visual Studio go to your Project properties and Choose `Settings`
You will find listed all your settings. From there verify that each setting you want to be change by user has scope `User`

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you can find detailed information on the difference between `User` and `Application` scope

Comment: I think the opposite is true. Application settings with a 'User' scope are stored in the current user's directory somewhere, not in the file that is stored with the app's directory.

Comment: @DaveVandenEyndeYou are correct. I found the user config files under Appdata/Local/{appname}